# Burger Menu with React Redux is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to make my own burger menu in react redux. But it has some problems that make it and another components can't be rendered. This is my `actions.js`:

```
const TOGGLE_MENU = 'TOGGLE_MENU';

export const toggleMenu = () => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_MENU
  };
};
```

This is my `burgerMenu.js` - the reducer:

```
const burgerMenu = (state = { isToggled: false }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_MENU:
        return { isToggled: !state.isToggled };
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

export default burgerMenu;
```

The `BurgerMenuContainer.js` - the container component:

```
import BurgerMenu from './BurgerMenu'
import { toggleMenu } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { isToggled: state.isToggled };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { onClick: () => dispatch(toggleMenu()) };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BurgerMenu);
```

The `BurgerMenu.js` - the presentational component:

```
const BurgerMenu = ({ isToggled, onClick }) => (
    <div onClick={ onClick } className={isToggled ? "burger-menu" : "burger-menu menu-on"}>
        <div className="burger"></div>  
    </div>
);

BurgerMenu.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isToggled: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default BurgerMenu;
```

And the `Header.js` contains Burger Menu Container:

```
import BurgerMenuContainer from './BurgerMenuContainer';

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
  <header className="header">
    <BurgerMenuContainer/>
  </header>);
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: You are not rendering anything in BurgerMenuContainer. Try to use render(){
return (<BurgerMenu  isToggled: this.props.isToggled/>)
}

Comment: @ashishsherawat I think the connect returns a Burger Menu component

Comment: Connect is the function which places your redux state properties to the component props.

Comment: So, I have to return the Burger Menu after the connect, right?